# split file by lines and keep the first string as a header for output files

Tags: bash, awk, split

I have the file that look like that:

```
t_#_3_0 v_0_17  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_1 v_0_144 v_1_17  v_2_20  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_2 v_0_143 v_1_233 v_2_238 u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_3 v_0_20  v_1_253 v_2_275 u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_4 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_90  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_5 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_30  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_6 v_0_19  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_7 v_0_20  v_1_7   v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_8 v_0_16  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
t_#_3_9 v_0_15  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
```

I would like to split it line by line and keep the first string as headers for my new files. My desired output should look like that.

```
file 1: t_#_3_0.txt (inside located line - t_#_3_0 v_0_17 v_1_20 v_2_78 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_1_2)
file 2: t_#_3_1.txt
file 3: t_#_3_2.txt
```

I tried `split` command, but it results in numerical indexes for output files.

I would appreciate your suggestions!

Thank you!

Olha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These results kinda surprised me. :)

#### `sed`

Just to pull something weird out of the toolbox as an example of why you should evaluate your methods now and then...

```
$: time sed -En 's/^([^ ]+)( .*)$/printf "%s%s\n" "\1" "\2" > \1.txt/e' file
real    0m0.859s
user    0m0.183s
sys     0m0.480s
```

I figured that would be slow, but it's nice to have in the toolbox just in case. Don't use pliers to drive nails.

#### `awk`

```
$: time awk '{ fn=$1".txt" ; print > fn ; close (fn) } ' file
real    0m0.141s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.077s
```

Predictably faster, and likely a lot for a larger file.

But the one that surprised me -

#### Pure `bash`

```
$: time while read line; do echo "$line" > "${line%%[   ]*}"; done < file
real    0m0.015s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.016s
```

## NOTE - *edited* to use spaces AND/OR tabs

`"${line%%[     ]*}"` has both a space and a tab between the square brackets `[     ]` as field delimiters.

I think the time gain here is in the file management overhead. `read` is notoriously slow, but the OS is good at handling its own I/O, I suppose.

Maybe someone can chime in with a more in-depth analysis?

Elaborating the test out to a sample size of 10k records closes the gap between `bash` and `awk` a lot -

```
$: for x in {0..9999}; do echo "t_${x}_3_0 v_0_17  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2"; done >| file

$: time while read line; do echo "$line" > "${line%% *}"; done < file
real    0m24.022s
user    0m2.360s
sys     0m11.938s

$: time awk '{ fn=$1".txt" ; print > fn ; close (fn) } ' file
real    0m27.284s
user    0m1.312s
sys     0m12.656s

$: $: time sed -En 's/^([^ ]+)( .*)$/printf "%s%s\n" "\1" "\2" > \1.txt/e' file
real    13m28.503s
user    1m48.374s
sys     8m22.970s
```

I suspect a lot of the difference with a smaller dataset is `awk`'s compile time, maybe?

Testing on 100k to confirm -

```
$: wc -c file # >5.5MB
5788890 file
```

`bash`:

```
real    8m42.666s
user    0m28.671s
sys     2m34.781s
```

`awk`:

```
real    8m15.096s
user    0m15.546s
sys     2m35.421s
```

I'm really surprised at how little difference there is.
I assume it's because *most* of the time is file I/O operations.

Comment: The sample data is too small to be used in benchmarking. Make it a couple megabytes, and awk will be faster, sed has no chance because it spawns a new sh instance for every line. There is nothing to analyse here

Comment: So, I tried to run it on another set of lines and it does not produce the output.


I think thee issue is delimiter between entities in the line. Am I correct?

Comment: is it a space or a tab?

Comment: This is an example of the input that I have tested:

`t_#_3_72 v_0_233 v_1_222 v_2_51 v_3_85 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3
t_#_3_73 v_0_233 v_1_222 v_2_51 v_3_55 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3
t_#_3_74 v_0_233 v_1_222 v_2_51 v_3_54 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3
t_#_3_75 v_0_238 v_1_137 v_2_214 v_3_50 u_0_1 u_0_2 u_0_3`

Comment: it has both tab and space delimiters

Comment: edited to use spaces AND/OR tabs; 
`"${line%%[  ]*}"` now has both a space and a tab between the square brackets `[  ]` as field delimiters. Try it again please.

Comment: In bash version, `while read fname line; do echo "$line" > "$fname"; done < file` should be faster slightly.

Comment: But it changes the data.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{name=$1 ".txt"; print >name; close(name)}' file
```

Variable `name` contains content of first column with suffix `.txt`. `print >name` writes complete current row to file `name`.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of the requirements:

- each line in source file is to be copied to a new file
- new file is named after the contents of field (column) #1

One `awk` solution (assuming raw data is in file `file.all`):

```
$ awk '{ fn=$1".txt" ; print > fn ; close (fn) } ' file.all
$ for f in t*#*txt
do
echo "+++++++++++++ $f"
cat $f
done

+++++++++++++ t_#_3_0.txt
t_#_3_0 v_0_17  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_1.txt
t_#_3_1 v_0_144 v_1_17  v_2_20  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_2.txt
t_#_3_2 v_0_143 v_1_233 v_2_238 u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_3.txt
t_#_3_3 v_0_20  v_1_253 v_2_275 u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_4.txt
t_#_3_4 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_90  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_5.txt
t_#_3_5 v_0_144 v_1_209 v_2_30  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_6.txt
t_#_3_6 v_0_19  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_7.txt
t_#_3_7 v_0_20  v_1_7   v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_8.txt
t_#_3_8 v_0_16  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
+++++++++++++ t_#_3_9.txt
t_#_3_9 v_0_15  v_1_20  v_2_78  u_0_1   u_0_2   u_1_2
```

Comment: looks like @Cyrus beat you by a minute with the same solution.